# Is there a "magic method" to access a list defined within a class through instance[0] rather than instance.list[0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

If I had the code:

```py
names = ["Dave", "John", "Bob"]
```

and I wanted to get Dave from names I would do:

```py
names[0]
```

If I now had the code

```py
class Friends:
    def __init__(self, *people):
        self.names = []
        for v in people:
            self.names.append(v)

names = Friends("Dave", "John", "Bob")
```

to get Dave now I would have to do:

```py
names.names[0]
```

Is there a *magic method* or something like that so that I can do:

```py
names[0]
```

again and get Dave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) as in:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = ["john", "arthur"]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.names[i]

print(MyClass()[0])
# john
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a list anywhere of all the magic methods bar doing dir(class)

Comment: here you go: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names